# Sum and difference 'is known', or 'are known'?

Tags: phrases

Which of the following is correct?

1. Given two numbers whose sum and difference is known, ...
2. Given two numbers whose sum and difference are known,...

Comment: I think it's largely a matter of *exact* context (and stylistic choice). If the context is one where any two specific values ***sum*** and ***difference*** are essentially being treated as a "matched pair" used *together* for some further computation I can't see anything wrong with treating the pair as singular... [*Each sum and difference **is** approximated ... by a corresponding parameterized variety of ellipsoids.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Each+sum+and+difference+is+approximated%22)

Comment: ...in fact, here are a couple of (perfectly valid, imho) written instances of [*sum and difference **is** known*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sum+and+difference+is+known%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(N.B the accepted answer is wrong -- see later in the answer for an updated answer)**

'Are' because we discussing 'two numbers'.

Same for 'two numbers whose sum is known'

'The sum of two numbers' would use 'is' because we are discussing 'the sum'

'The sum and difference of two numbers' would use 'are' because we are discussing 'the sum and difference'

**Edit**

Whoops. I got this wrong. It's 'are' because 'sum and difference' are two items.

Comment: Thank you. English is not my first language, so this is useful.

Comment: regarding the second line?? So then we should have "I, whose opinion am unimportant,"?? I don't think it works that way.

Comment: @PhilSweet the 'I' would use 'am', but 'opinion' takes 'is'. "**I**, whose *opinion* *is* unimportant, **am** still going to have my say"

Comment: @PhilSweet ah! I see your point -- will correct. Thanks.

Comment: You should just correct the error, the edit is confusing. I presume you meant to say that the OP should use the plural verb because "sum" and "difference" are two separate items.

Comment: I've added a header in bold to explain the answer is wrong -- I don't like changing the content completely, since this was the OP's accepted answer. Seems incorrect to change the answer significantly after acceptance.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I suppose that's quite noble of you. I would still edit the answer, users can see the edit history by clicking on the time stamp.